# Blogging platform that supports guest-posting

Tags: looking-for-a-script, blog, web-applications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Content Management System (CMS) should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-should-i-use)

I'm looking for a blogging engine (hosted or downloadable) that will allow:

- guest posting (anyone can register an account and post)
- file-attachments (you can attach files to posts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Wordpress: http://www.wordpress.com/ (the hosted version) or http://www.wordpress.org/ (the self-hosted version).

Comment: Thanks! Does it support guest posting? So I don't have to approve anyone to be an author, users just pick username/pass and post?

Comment: Also I don't think wordpress allow non-media file attachments (like ZIP files or PDFs)

Comment: Yes, It supports both of those features.

Comment: just checked the hosted version at wordpress.com and public posting is not possible... Looking into the self-hosted version.

Comment: You need to set the default user role to contributor or author in order to enable people to register and post on your blog. Also, don't forget to enable registration (if you haven't already).

Answer (score 1):

BuddyPress (BuddyPress.org) is a great addon for Wordpress which allows for multiple blogs.

Wordpress alone also provides excellent access controls so that guest posters can post to a main blog without full access.